# Azure Internal LB not reachable even though same config works if LB is external

Tags: azure, load-balancing, kubernetes, azure-networking

I have a Kubernetes AKS cluster running in a Site-2-Site connected subnet. Kubernetes is able to automatically create an external LB for a service. This ends up with a config that looks like this:

- **Frontend IP config:** `52.123.123.12`
- **Backend pools:** kubernetes (2 virtual machines)
- **Health probes:**

  - Protocol: `TCP`, Port: `30231`, Interval: `5`, Unhealthy threshold: `2` (Note: `30231` is the port where HTTPS is reachable on each node)
  - Protocol: `TCP`, Port: `32525`, Interval: `5`, Unhealthy threshold: `2` (Note: `32525` is the port where HTTP is reachable on each node)
- **Load balancing rules:**

  - IPv4, Frontend IP: `52.123.123.12`, Port: `443`, Backend port: `443`, Backend pool: `kubernetes (2 virtual machines)`, Health probe: `the one for 30231`
  - IPv4, Frontend IP: `52.123.123.12`, Port: `80`, Backend port: `80`, Backend pool: `kubernetes (2 virtual machines)`, Health probe: `the one for 32525`
- **Inboud NAT rules**: none

*The external LB routes everything just fine*

Now what I'm trying to do is to *manually create an identical LB like this, except **internal***. I've created an ILB, and added the backend pool, health probes and LB rules with the exact same config as the external LB above (with the exception of the IP).

The internal LB is on IP `10.240.140.5`, which is the same subnet as the nodes themselves `10.240.140.0/24`. I am able to reach both ports `30231,32525` on both nodes `10.240.140.1,10.240.140.2` directly, but if I try to reach the ILB (`10.240.140.5:80` or `10.240.140.5:443`), the connection just times out. Even though the same exact configuration of pool + probes + rules worked just fine on an external LB.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The external LB uses the public virtual IP addresss with the cloud service that hosts the virtual machines. The internal LB is on IP 10.240.140.5 which is a private IP address that we can not use to directly connect to a LB or VM publicly.

If you want to access the internal VM from local network, you can use a [P2S VPN gateway](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-point-to-site-resource-manager-portal) on Azure portal to route traffic to the Vnet from local network.